# Prove the inclusion-exclusion formula for $P(A \cup B \cup C) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove the following equation.

$P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) - P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$

I started with this..

$P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A \cup B) \cup C$

I think that I may go on with **De Morgan laws** ..
but I'm not sure which are the right steps.
Can you give me some hint? Of course I'm not asking for the solution, just a "way to follow".

Comment: Are you familiar with the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have
$$P(A \cup B \cup C) = P((A \cup B) \cup C)
\\=P(A \cup B) +P( C)-P((A \cup B) \cap C)
\\=P(A )+P(B)-P(A \cap B) +P( C)-P((A\cap C) \cup (B \cap C)
\\ =P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) - P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- This is a special case of probabilistic version of [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).
- With $n=3$ (you have three sets) the most mechanic approach would be to split your sets into *disjoint* parts (there would be $2^3 = 8$ of these), that is,
  \begin{align}
  \Omega_{\varnothing} &= \{\omega \in \Omega \mid \omega \notin A, \omega \notin B, \omega \notin C\} \\
  \Omega_{A} &= \{\omega \in \Omega \mid \omega \in A, \omega \notin B, \omega \notin C\} \\
  \Omega_{B} &= \{\omega \in \Omega \mid \omega \notin A, \omega \in B, \omega \notin C\} \\
  &\;\vdots \\
  \Omega_{AB} &= \{\omega \in \Omega \mid \omega \in A, \omega \in B, \omega \notin C\} \\
  &\;\vdots\\
  \Omega_{ABC} &= \{\omega \in \Omega \mid \omega \in A, \omega \in B, \omega \in C\}
  \end{align}
  and then use $P(X \cup Y) = P(X) + P(Y)$ for disjoint $X$ and $Y$. Just expand both sides of your formula and it should match.
- A less mindless approach would be to prove it as above for $n=2$, namely $$P(X \cup Y) = P(X) + P(Y) - P(X \cap Y)$$ and then apply it several times, first with $X = A \cup B$, $Y = C$, and then again for terms like $P(A \cup B)$.
- Finally, you could always try induction (i.e. prove for general $n$), however, that would require more work.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$